# Finding the corresponding row value of highest row number in another column

Tags: sql

I have a table similar to this one below. I want to create New_Column that finds the highest number for the selected date, and returns the date, while returning null for all of the other numbers. I was thinking of adding in a case when, but wasn't sure how to incorporate it.

```
Date         Number   New_Column
2021-03-18     1          null
2021-03-18     8          null
2021-03-18     20       2021-03-18
2021-04-18     1          null
2021-04-18     7          null
2021-04-18     11      2021-04-18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when number = max(number) over (partition by date)
             then date
        end) as new_column
from t;
```

Note:  If there are ties for the highest value and you only want one to be marked

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by date order by number desc) = 1
             then date
        end) as new_column
from t;
```

Comment: These queries would normally work, but the date column in my query is calculated using a window function, and SQL won't allow me to partition by a window function. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: @JayP . . . You can use a CTE or subquery to calculate the date and then put this in an outer query.